# Updating values inside an object as soon as other array changes in Javascript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data/json in react of the following form stored in useState as follows:

```
const [Data, setData] = useState([]);
  
{
  "trees":{
     "name":"a",
     "age":"9",
     "height":"10",
     "location":"park"
  },
  "cars":{
     "name":"b",
     "age":"3",
     "height":"10",
     "location":"park"
  },
  "bikes":{
     "name":"c",
     "age":"110",
     "height":"10",
     "location":"park"
  }
}
```

Using WebSockets, I am getting another array of objects related to this data as follows:
"cars":

```
[{
         "name":"b",
         "age":"3",
         "height":"99",
         "location":"park"
      },
      {
         "name":"c",
         "age":"734",
         "height":"9",
         "location":"park"
      }]
```

As can be seen in the above array, the value age and height are different for some objects than the original data. Therefore, what I want to do is that I want to update these values for respective things in the original data upon receiving from WebSocket data.
I can't figure out the `javascript` to do so since the original data is of key-value pair form and updated data is an array of objects and setData every time new data comes from WebSocket.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. We have local Data as object and Array of Objects from WebSocket.

```
const Data = {
  "trees":{
     "name":"a",
     "age":"9",
     "height":"10",
     "location":"park"
  },
  "cars":{
     "name":"b",
     "age":"3",
     "height":"10",
     "location":"park"
  },
  "bikes":{
     "name":"c",
     "age":"110",
     "height":"10",
     "location":"park"
  }
}

const array = [{
             "name":"b",
             "age":"3",
             "height":"99",
             "location":"park"
          },
          {
             "name":"c",
             "age":"734",
             "height":"9",
             "location":"park"
          }]
```

Get values and keys from our local object.

```
const values = Object.values(Data)
const keys = Object.keys(Data)
```

Loop through the array from web socket and values from above and compare it and update the state.

```
array.forEach((arr) => {
    values.forEach((obj, i) => {
        if(arr.name === obj.name){
            Data[keys[i]] = arr
        }
    })
})

console.log(Data)
```

You may need to use useEffect to run the above loop everything new data comes in through socket.

Output:

```
{
    bikes: {name: 'c', age: '734', height: '9', location: 'park'}
    cars: {name: 'b', age: '3', height: '99', location: 'park'}
    trees: {name: 'a', age: '9', height: '10', location: 'park'}
}
```

Comment: You should note that objects are a kind of pointer and changing them directly will change the state directly. We do not have this permission in the react so it is better to do it with "Object.assign".

Comment: `You may need to use useEffect to run the above loop everything new data comes in through socket.` Cant I directly put it in websocket function.

Comment: @miladshiriyan What I was thinking was storing the whole data in another variable and then doing operation on that variable and finally setting the original Data using setData. Is this method correct and effective

Comment: @ashok and you help me implement the same using `map`

Comment: @VATSALJAIN Yes, you can, but eventually update the status with setState.